# Reading a line with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I know it is a basic question, but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer. A link to the answer would be more than enough.

I have a html file like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
      <p>Question: &#x34;&#x38;&#xA0;</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I read the string between

```
<p>
```

and

```
</p>?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can access that P tag (i.e document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]), then you can get access the property `innerHTML` to retrieve the text or `textContext`

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
console.log( p.innerHTML || p.textContext );
```

Comment: Glad this was useful!

Answer (score 4):

`var p =document.getElementsByTagName('p');p[0].textContent`

Comment: Sorry guys. The getElementsByTagName always returns an array. Only getElementById returns one single element. Have modified the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent;
```